# Accidentally pluged red ttl cabe into either tx or rx

Tags: gpio

I accidentally plugged the red 5v cable into either the tx or rx pin and tried to boot the pi. Can this cause damage?

Comment: If it used to boot but no longer does it sounds like you have destroyed the Pi.  Do any LEDs flash during boot?  Does the CPU get very hot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, feeding any voltage over 3.3V or less than 0V into a Pi GPIO can destroy the GPIO and/or the Pi.

The UART RX/TX pins are GPIO.